# logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,1] and labels shape [80000]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, pickle

I am not able to run this part of the notebook
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,1] and labels shape [80000]
[[{{node loss_2/activation_8_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] this keeps coming

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one neuron in your final dense layer which is followed by a sigmoid activation layer. This means you're doing binary classification. Therefore, you should compile as follows:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```